# Rearrange Rows(ID) after adding or deleting dynamically created rows using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need help here.

I found few related answers but couldn't apply it in my case.

I need to add and delete rows dynamically with help of Add and Delete button in each row.
The one column is having rowid which also needs to be rearranged on adding or deleting of rows.
Suppose we are having three rows and we deleted the second row then row id column should get rearranged i.e. row id of third row should now become two(2).
Similarly we need to rearrange the rowid column if we are adding the new rows.

Please let me know if further details are required for the  problem description.

Editing with Sample Code:-

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
<table style="width:300px">
<tr>
  <th>RowId</th>
  <th>Description</th>      
  <th>Points</th>
  <th>Add</th>      
  <th>Remove</th> 
  </tr>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Desc1</td>        
  <td>50</td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src="" width="43" height="20" />Add</a></td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src="" width="43" height="20" />Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
 <td>2</td>
  <td>Desc2</td>        
  <td>50</td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src="" width="43" height="20" />Add</a></td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src="" width="43" height="20" />Remove</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>3</td>
  <td>Desc3</td>        
  <td>50</td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src="" width="43" height="20" />Add</a></td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src="" width="43" height="20" />Remove</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>4</td>
  <td>Desc4</td>        
  <td>50</td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src="" width="43" height="20" />Add</a></td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src="" width="43" height="20" />Remove</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some example code of grid (with rows and columns)?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for replying .I have edited question with sample code. I need to Add and remove the rows by using add/remove link(which is an image).What I need is the first column(RowID) should also get rearranged if I am adding or deleting the rows.

Comment: where is the sample code you added?

Comment: Hi,Sorry for confusion if any.Earlier I hadn't uploaded the html code,updated with the sample html which is in question above. I have just uploaded the html part.On clicking the Add button user should get a text box to enter.

Comment: Hi,here is one fiddle which is nearly same what I am trying to do:-http://jsfiddle.net/2nzgG/30/

Comment: In this I need Add button in each row along with Remove Button and S.No. functionality should be same as the above fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

After adding or deleting rows you can try this

```
$('table').find('tr').find('td:first').each(function(index){    
    $(this).text(index+1);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B2WwR/)